# PHP Display data based on student_name, but not based on student_username

Tags: php, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap

I have a difficulty to display an item of a student based on the `student_name`. Previously I was able to display an item based on `student_username` but not using `student_name`. but now I want to use `student_name` to display the item which from `student_name`. I attached together with my code part.

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Welcome -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <?php
            include("connection.php");
            $username=$_SESSION['username'];
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT student_name FROM register WHERE student_username='$username'");
            $ee=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            ?>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><b>&nbsp;Hello ! </b>Welcome Back <b><?php echo $ee['student_name']; ?> </b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end  Welcome -->
</div>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                   <div class="table table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>S.no</th>
                           <th>Parcel Number</th>
                           <th>Date Recieved</th>
                           <th>Date of Collected</th>
                           <th>Recieved Time</th>
                           <th>Collect Time</th>
                           <th>Status</th>
                           <th>Sent By</th>
                            <th>Sent To</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                     <?php
        include("connection.php");
        $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_parcel WHERE send_to='$username'");
        $i=1;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
            echo '<tr class="record"><td>'.$i++.'</td><td>'.$row['date_recieve'].'</td><td>'.$row['date_collect'].'</td><td>'.$row['recieve_time'].'</td><td>'.$row['collect_time'].'</td><td>'.$row['status'].'</td><td>'.$row['sender_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['send_to'].'</td></tr>';
        }
?>
```

[image: Student Dashboard]
[image: Admin panel add item]

```
add_parcel table = parcel_id,parcel_num,date_recieve,date_collect,recieve_time,collect_time,status,sender_name,send_to

register table = student_id,student_username,student_name,student_address,student_age,student_icenumber, student_email,student_phone,password
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. What is the current output and what is the desired output? You run 2 queries; I assume you want the first query to be changed so you select by `student_name` instead of `student_username`? If I'm right, I think you should store the student's name in the `$_SESSION` variable if it isn't there already, so you essentialy can do `SELECT student_name FROM register WHERE student_name='{$_SESSION['name']}'`. which seems weird, cos you already have the student's name ?

Comment: So here is the situation. Student is login using their student_username. Admin will add an item such date, time, sender name and send_to. For the send_to attribute admin will select from the drop list where it will listed student_name not the student_username. Let say admin select send_to = Jack, then jack is login using his own id for example jack username is student1, then it will display the item which under jack. student_username = student_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Welcome -->
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <?php
                include("connection.php");
                $username=$_SESSION['username'];
                $student_name=$_SESSION['student_name'];
                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT student_name FROM register WHERE student_name='$student_name'");
                $ee=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            ?>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><b>&nbsp;Hello ! </b>Welcome Back <b><?php echo $ee['student_name']; ?> </b>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end  Welcome -->
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="table table-responsive">
             <table class="table table-hover">
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>S.no</th>
                         <th>Parcel Number</th>
                         <th>Date Recieved</th>
                         <th>Date of Collected</th>
                         <th>Recieved Time</th>
                         <th>Collect Time</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                         <th>Sent By</th>
                         <th>Sent To</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>

                 <?php
                     include("connection.php");
                     $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_parcel WHERE send_to='$student_name'");
                     $i=1;
                     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                         echo '<tr class="record"><td>'.$i++.'</td><td>'.$row['date_recieve'].'</td><td>'.$row['date_collect'].'</td><td>'.$row['recieve_time'].'</td><td>'.$row['collect_time'].'</td><td>'.$row['status'].'</td><td>'.$row['sender_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['send_to'].'</td></tr>';
                     }
```

Comment: its doesnt work <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i><b>&nbsp;Hello ! </b>Welcome Back <b><?php echo $ee['student_name']; ?> 
The student_name is not displayed after all .

Comment: i think the problem is this part $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_parcel WHERE send_to='$username'"); it work when is change to $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_parcel'"); but when i put agrument WHERE send_to='$username' it doesnt display anything on the dasboard.